# How do I run below if/else steps for windows bash script in yaml azure devOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

```
steps:
     - checkout: A
     - script: dir
       workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
     - script: | 
          if [ -f abc.yaml ]; then
          # this is used to check if the file is exist: if [ -f your-file-here ]
          echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=FILEEXISTS;isOutput=true]true"
          else
          echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=FILEEXISTS;isOutput=true]false"
          fi
       name: printvar
```

While I run below , code I get error `-f was unexpected at this time. ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '255'`

Comment: While I run below , code I get error

       - script: | 
          if [ -f abc.yml ]; then
          echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=FILEEXISTS;isOutput=true]true"
          else
          echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=FILEEXISTS;isOutput=true]false"
          fi
       name: printvar     
    
error is below    
    -f was unexpected at this time.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '255'.

Answer (score 0):

The bash script looks fine, however the [script keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#script) is a shortcut that will use different script interpreters depending on platform:

> The script keyword is a shortcut for the command-line task. The task
> runs a script using `cmd.exe` on Windows and `bash` on other platforms.

Use the [bash keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#bash) or the [shell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/shell-script?view=azure-devops) task directly instead to run a bash script also on windows agents

> The bash keyword is a shortcut for the shell script task. The task
> runs a script in `bash` on Windows, macOS, and Linux.

```yaml
steps:
  - checkout: A
  - script: dir
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  - bash: | 
      if [ -f abc.yaml ]; then
        # this is used to check if the file is exist: if [ -f your-file-here ]
        echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=FILEEXISTS;isOutput=true]true"
      else
        echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=FILEEXISTS;isOutput=true]false"
      fi
    name: printvar
```

Comment: I am not sure if I have described correctly my bad - I am trying to find if a file exists or not on windows server (the file is not .sh or a linux based). I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

> -f was unexpected at this time. ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '255'

Test with your yaml sample , I could reproduce the same issue on windows server.

[image]

The root cause of this issue is that the script is run with the Command Line task instead of Bash task.

To solve this issue, you could refer to the following two methods:

1.Use [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) to run the command:

```
- bash: |
   if [ -f abc.yaml ]; then
   echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=FILEEXISTS;isOutput=true]true"
   else
   echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=FILEEXISTS;isOutput=true]false"
   fi
  workingDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)' 
  displayName: 'Bash Script'
```

2.If you still want to use script parameters, you could try to run the following script:

```
steps:
- script: |
   if exist abc.yaml (
       echo ##vso[task.setVariable variable=fileexist;isOutput=true]true
   ) else (
       echo ##vso[task.setVariable variable=fileexist;isOutput=true]false
   )
  workingDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- powershell: |
   # Write your PowerShell commands here.
   
   Write-Host "$(CMDLINE.FILEEXIST)"
  
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

**Note:** You could set the **workingDirectory** parameter in the task to confirm the path you need to check.